# Back up particular package and its dependencies

Tags: linux, fedora, software-installation, backup, dependencies

My question is: can we take a backup of a particular package and its dependencies?

For example, if we install VLC it requires dependencies like kde filesystem,libcaca.so.0 etc.. can we take a backup of VLC and its dependencies?  I'm using Fedora15

Comment: Do you mean copying the actual rpm files used for the install? Search for where `yum` keeps its cache. Otherwise, can you be a bit more specific about "backup"?

Comment: i mean yum install, because it automatically installs required dependencies. so if we can take the backup of those files then we can use it when we install it another time without using yum, that is my intention. is it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install any rpm packet from the net with yum it will saved in /var/cache/yum

Please, also read documentation about more specific options- [here](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Core/5/html/Software_Management_Guide/sn-yum-caching.html)

Comment: Sergei, simple and clear. Thanks for the link.